# selecting and manipulating individual CSV columns in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to use a function much like this.....

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/$importedFile.csv","r");
    while ($line =  fgetcsv($file))
        {
        $csv_data[] = $line;
        }
    fclose($file);
```

...to load CSV values. This is gravy but now I wish to select individual columns by their array number. I believe I want to select it with something like this, but cannot find any clarity.

```
$csv_data[2] = $line;
```

This however just shows second (third) row of data rather than column.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the whole file in memory or will you be processing the lines individually?

Processing individually:

`$line` is already an array.  If you want the 3rd column, use `$line[2]`

Processing after reading the whole file:

`$csv_data[$lineNo][$columnNo]`

Comment: This seems to be correct, and have found that this does produce results, however each line now only contains the word "array". Could you help me with what I am clearly missing? apologies.

Comment: just needed $i=0 $ $i++ either side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputfiledelimiter = ",";    
if (($handle = fopen($PathOfCsvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {       
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $inputfiledelimiter)) !== FALSE) 
        {
            //get data from $data
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your CSV file is now split up in lines, that is all.

No concept of columns yet in that structure.
So you need to split the lines into columns.

Or, much better, let PHP do that for you: Have a look at fgetcsv() and the associated functions:

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php